# Array.prototype.find() in PHP that returns reference

Tags: php, arrays, function, reference

I'm trying to make a function that works like Array.prototype.find() in javascript but for PHP.

My array have that structure :

```
$array = [
     ["id" => 54, "type" => 5, "content" => [
          ["id" => 99, "type" => 516],
          ["id" => 88, "type" => 464],
          ["id" => 41, "type" => 845]]
     ],
     ["id" => 54, "type" => 55, "content"=> [
          ["id" => 54, "type" => 578],
          ["id" => 54, "type" => 354],
          ["id" => 75, "type" => 458]]
     ],
     ["id" => 65, "type" => 59, "content" => [
          ["id" => 87, "type" => 5454],
          ["id" => 65, "type" => 245],
          ["id" => 65, "type" => 24525]]
     ]
];
```

Then I created my function to search like in javascript :

```
function array_find($array, $function){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if($function($value)){
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
$id=54;
$type=55;
$mycontent = array_find(
    $array,
    function($foo) {
        global $id;
        global $type;
        return $foo["id"] == $id && $foo["type"] == $type;
    }
)["content"];
```

It's working. However **i want the returned result to be a reference and not a value**, so i can later add/remove elements inside of the returned array.

How can i do this?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/php/how-to-pass-variables-by-reference-in-php.html#pass-by-reference-4

Comment: Yeah, i guess i need to use the & operator. I tried at many different places in my code but without any success...

Comment: Show your tries. We can't help with what we cannot see.

Comment: Why do you need a reference? Are you planning on mutating a row which should effect the original array?

Comment: Yes I need to change the content of "content" in the original array

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot simply return the index of the qualifying row, then access and directly mutate `$array[$index]['content']`? You code looks overengineered and your input array structure is invalid (not enough closing square braces).

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I fixed array structure. Yeah i could go everytime for $array[$index]['content']. I just would have like more convenient way of doing it since PHP is supposed to handle references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer this question without completely abandoning your original code.

If you want to be able return the reference for a qualifying row, then the only way that I can think of is to

1. Convert your array of arrays to an array of objects,
2. Add `&` to the function name declaration, and
3. Use `= &` to declare the reference variable in the global scope.

Adjusted Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/k1KLp))

```
function &getRowReference($array, $fn) {
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        if ($fn($row)) {
            return $row->content;
        }
    }
}

function qualifyingRow($row) {
    global $id;
    global $type;
    return $row->id == $id && $row->type == $type;
}

$id = 54;
$type = 55;

$array = [
    (object)[
        "id" => 54,
        "type" => 5,
        "content" => [
            ["id" => 99, "type" => 516],
            ["id" => 88, "type" => 464],
            ["id" => 41, "type" => 845]
        ]
    ],
    (object)[
        "id" => 54,
        "type" => 55,
        "content" => [
            ["id" => 54, "type" => 578],
            ["id" => 54, "type" => 354],
            ["id" => 75, "type" => 458]
        ]
    ],
    (object)[
        "id" => 65,
        "type" => 59,
        "content" => [
            ["id" => 87, "type" => 5454],
            ["id" => 65, "type" => 245],
            ["id" => 65, "type" => 24525]
        ]
    ]
];

$ref = &getRowReference($array, 'qualifyingRow');

$ref = 'this has been changed';

var_export($array);
```

I don't think that I would bother going to all this effort myself.  I would probably leave the data structure in its original state, return the index of the qualifying row, then access, mutate, and store the data using the index.

Here is a relevant page to offer some additional commentary and warning about returning references: [Return by reference in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7455627/2943403)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a proper answer to my question. Indeed it's complicated and I would just use index but at least you offered a solution with references :) I'm surprised that what is so easy in js... array.find(row=>row["id"]==id && row["type"]==type); looks so verbose in php

Comment: Yes, PHP has different rules and behaviors around variable scopes and the treatment of arrays versus objects. Declaring a reference variable can be as simple as https://3v4l.org/P4DtF if you don't require functional-style syntax.

Comment: This is very interesting @mickmackusa , thanks a lot. I don't particulary need functional style, i'm just used to it. However i'm not sure to understand why what works with objects doesn't work with arrays? https://3v4l.org/NaZX1

Comment: @user PHP objects are modifiable by reference as a default behavior, arrays are not.  You can achieve this behavior with arrays by simply adding an ampersand in front of `$row` in `foreach()`. https://3v4l.org/U7mcJ .  This also works: https://3v4l.org/KQQZ7 Note that neither snippet handles the possibility of no match in the array -- so these snippets are not ready to paste into a professional application.

Comment: Very usefull. I learned a lot tooday. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PHP function that works like the JavaScript [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function.

I believe the code is self-explanatory, but if you have any questions feel free to ask me.

```
// JavaScript-like Array.find() function
$array_find = function($an_array, $callback_function) {
    $data_found = null;
    foreach ($an_array as $an_array_index => $an_object) {
        $is_data_found = $callback_function($an_object, $an_array_index, $an_array);
        if ($is_data_found) {
            $data_found = $an_object;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $data_found;
};
```

**Usage in an ordinary array:**

```
$numbers = [12, 34, 27, 23, 65, 93, 36, 87, 4, 254];

$even_number_found = $array_find($numbers, fn($number) => $number % 2 === 0);
echo("even number found: $even_number_found<br /><br />");
// even numbers only: 12

$odd_number_found = $array_find($numbers, fn($number) => $number % 2 !== 0);
echo("odd number found: $odd_number_found<br /><br />");
// odd numbers only: 27
```

**Usage in an associative array:**
(JavaScript-like Array of Objects / JavaScript-like JSON)

```
$products = [
    [
        'id' => 'id_1',
        'name' => 'name_1',
        'variant' => [
            'is_free_shipping' => false,
            'price' => 290,
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'id_2',
        'name' => 'name_2',
        'variant' => [
            'is_free_shipping' => true,
            'price' => 232,
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'id_3',
        'name' => 'name_3',
        'variant' => [
            'is_free_shipping' => false,
                'price' => 140,
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'id_4',
        'name' => 'name_4',
        'variant' => [
            'is_free_shipping' => true,
            'price' => 499,
        ]
    ]
];

$product_found = $array_find($products, fn($product) => @$product['id'] === 'id_3');
$product_found_formatted = json_encode($product_found, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo("product found: $product_found_formatted<br /><br />");
// product found: { "id": "id_3", "name": "name_3", "variant": { "is_free_shipping": false, "price": 140 } }

$product_found = $array_find($products, fn($product) => @$product['variant']['price'] >= 200 && @$product['variant']['is_free_shipping'] === true);
$product_found_formatted = json_encode($product_found, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo("product found: $product_found_formatted<br /><br />");
// product found: { "id": "id_2", "name": "name_2", "variant": { "is_free_shipping": true, "price": 232 } }
```

**Usage using OP data:**

```
$array = [
    ["id" => 54, "type" => 5, "content" => [
        ["id" => 99, "type" => 516],
        ["id" => 88, "type" => 464],
        ["id" => 41, "type" => 845]]
    ],
    ["id" => 54, "type" => 55, "content"=> [
        ["id" => 54, "type" => 578],
        ["id" => 54, "type" => 354],
        ["id" => 75, "type" => 458]]
    ],
    ["id" => 65, "type" => 59, "content" => [
        ["id" => 87, "type" => 5454],
        ["id" => 65, "type" => 245],
        ["id" => 65, "type" => 24525]]
    ]
];

$OP_data_found = $array_find($array, fn($foo) => @$foo['id'] === 54 && @$foo['type'] === 55);
$OP_data_found_formatted = json_encode($OP_data_found, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo("OP data found: $OP_data_found_formatted");
// OP data found: { "id": 54, "type": 55, "content": [ { "id": 54, "type": 578 }, { "id": 54, "type": 354 }, { "id": 75, "type": 458 } ] }
```